# Что не так с Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Когда отправляю POST-запрос через postman на /oauth/token
я вношу параметры username, password, grant_type=password (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
Мне приходит ответ:

```
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "Missing grant type"
```

Замечу, что я это делал без режима отладки. Запрос идет в TokenEndpoint там и обрабатывается.

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = {"/oauth/token"},
    method = {RequestMethod.POST}
)
public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> postAccessToken(Principal principal, @RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {
...
}
```

В parameters должны быть как раз данные username= и т.д.
Когда прохожу через режим отладки у меня parameters size=0.
Углубляясь, ставлю точку отладки в ApplicationFilterChain сюда:

```
} else {
        this.internalDoFilter(request, response);
}
```

Он несколько раз вызывается (request.getParameterMap() выдает как раз мои параметры), потом переходит в TokenEndpoin, и о чудо, вижу свои параметры. После вижу выданный токен в ответе.

С чем это может быть связано, что без такого дебага я не могу получить нормально токен?

Answer (score 0):

Очень странно. На одном из конфигурационных файлов, который относился к инициализации Swagger, стояла аннотация @EnableWebMvc. После того как ее убрал, токен стал выдаваться в нормальном виде